# intel dg31pr heat issues

Tags: motherboard

I have got Intel 8400 processor installed on a DG31PR board. My board gets hot quite quickly and the temperature hovers around 50-65 C at normal load. I have got a good cooling system but I wonder if its a problem in my mobo. Can you guys kindly suggest what to do? My processor runs fine and stands at 30-32 C. Thanks.

Regards,

Adnan

Answer (score 1):

Personally, 50-65 doesn't seem *that* bad compared to some of the in production systems I see.

The CPU zone is the most important and upgrading the heatsinc usually does the job, but your CPU seems fine. There isn't really much you can do for other zones on your motherboard other than upgrade case fans, but again, I wouldn't really worry at those temperature.

Also, to reassure you, your system should switch itself off before it reaches any critical temperate that can actually do damage to the system.